# Binomial GLMM with categorical predictors: p-values?

Tags: r, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, p-value, glmm

My data has a binary response (correct/incorrect), one continuous predictor `score`, three categorical predictors (`race`, `sex`, `emotion`) and a random intercept for the random factor `subj`. All predictors are within-subject. One of the categorical factor has 3 levels, the other have two.

I need advice on obtaining "global" p-values for each categorical factor (in an "ANOVA like" way)

---

Here is how I proceed :

I fitted a binomial GLMM using 'glmer' from the lme4 package (because 'glmmML' doesn't compute on my data and glmmPQL does not provide AIC) and did model selection using `drop1` repeatedly until no more terms can be dropped. Here is the final model (let's assume it has been validated):

```
library(lme4)
M5 <- glmer(acc ~ race + sex + emotion + sex:emotion + race:emotion + score +(1|subj), 
        family=binomial, data=subset)
# apparently using family with lmer is deprecated 
drop1(M5, test="Chisq")
summary(M5)
```

`drop1` gives p-values for the higher level terms only (the two 2-way interactions + `score`). 
`summary`gives p-values for every term, but separates the different levels of each categorical factor.

How can I get "global" p-values for each factor? I need to report them even if they are not the most relevant or meaningful estimates of signifiance here. How should I proceed? I tried searching on the web and ended up reading about likelihood ratios or the "Wald test" but I am not sure if or how this would apply here.

(PS: This is a duplicate from my "anonymous" post here that needed editing: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90487/binomial-mixed-model-with-categorical-predictors-model-selection-and-getting-p Sorry about that.)

Comment: use `afex::mixed` as in `mixed(acc ~ race + sex + emotion + sex:emotion + race:emotion + score +(1|subj), family=binomial, data=subset, method = "LRT")`. To obtain p-values based on parametric bootstrap, you can use `method = "PB"` (but you will need to set the number of samples, see help). Also, you most likely need random slopes for your within-subject factors. Your random effects structure seems unreasonable!

Comment: did you look at `?pvalues` in the `lme4` package ... ? in addition to `afex::mixed`, it also suggests `car::Anova` and `lmerTest::anova` ...

Comment: @Ben Bolker : Thanks, I did not know about the `?pvalues`help section. However, apparently neither `car::Anova` (which I had tried prior to posting) nor `lmer::anova`work for GLMMs.

Comment: @Henrik: many thanks, I'm trying that now. I favored the most simple random effect structure because I am unsure about how to specify the random slope properly (especially, should I update it as some interactions are dropped in the fixed effect part?).

Comment: @Henrik : I tried  `mixed(acc ~ race + sex + emotion + sex:emotion + race:emotion + score +(1+sex|subj), family=binomial, data=subset, type = 3, method = "LRT")` as suggested (after selecting random then fixed effects) but this gives an error:

`Fitting 8 (g)lmer() models:
[.
Erreur dans lme4::glFormula(formula = acc ~ 0 + m.matrix[, -1L] + (1 + sex |  : 
  rank of X = 10 < ncol(X) = 16`
I don't think my design matrix is wrong. Have you encountered this error before?

Comment: note aside @Henrik : wow.. are you the one who wrote `mixed`? i feel.. humbled :)

Comment: @user42174 this error indicates that you have structurally missings in your data (i.e., completely empty cells). And if we should feel humbled then because of the presence of the maintainer of `lme4`, Ben Bolker (although his comment is slightly mislieading in this case as both of his suggestions do not support GLMMs iirc).

Comment: @Henrik it works now! p-values look good considering the outputs of `glmer`and `drop1`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user42174 or @Henrik, post as answer?  (I didn't pay attention to the distinctions about which methods work on GLMMs -- perhaps I should sort this out and add the information to `?pvalues` ...)

Comment: PS are you sure `car::Anova` doesn't work? `library(lme4); library(car); example(glmer); Anova(gm1)` does give results (although it uses Wald chi-square tests, not LRT or PB)

Comment: @Ben Bolker I got an error saying something like "$ not defined for S4 object" or something like this... `pvalues?`does stipulates that those methods do not work for GLMMs if i remember well. Thanks for your work with `lme4` by the way!

Comment: lme4 1.1-6 (1.1-5 should be the same for these purposes), car 2.0-19 ?

Comment: No, lme4_1.0-4 and car_2.0-18. Is it because of the old version of lme4 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy-Paste of the answer from @Henrik:

> use `afex::mixed` as in `mixed(acc ~ race + sex + emotion + sex:emotion + race:emotion + score +(1|subj), family=binomial, data=subset, method = "LRT")`. To obtain p-values based on parametric bootstrap, you can use `method = "PB"` (but you will need to set the number of samples, see help).
>
> Also, you most likely need random slopes for your within-subject factors. Your random effects structure seems unreasonable!

Answer (score 1):

Use the library `car`

```
M5 <- glmer(acc ~ race + sex + emotion + sex:emotion + race:emotion + score +(1|subj), family=binomial, data=subset)

library(car)

Anova(Ms)
```

Comment: OP says in comments that `car::Anova` doesn't work with `glmer` results. Did you test this? (OP may be mistaken, but I think it's worth saying that explicitly in your answer if they are.)

Comment: This is a bit late, but for posterity: yes, at the moment, `car::Anova` will produce p-values for `glmer` results. Note that the original question is now several years old, but `car` still (2017) does not appear to officially support glmer in its documentation. I'm not sure of the exact method it uses to obtain these p-values.

Comment: Yes, I have done some analysis with repeated measurements design, with binomial answers, the Anova function of the car library carries out the analysis of Wald with the chi-square distribution.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf

Answer (score -1):

```
library(lme4)            
model=glmer(hospitalisation~age_cat+sexe+mectizan+doublelecture2+(1 | village), Loaloa, family = "binomial")
library(afex)  ###Global p-value
mixed(hospitalisation~age_cat+sexe+mectizan+doublelecture2+(1 | village), Loaloa, family = "binomial", method = "LRT")

library(broom.mixed) ###Other p-values (not global)
tidy(model,conf.int=TRUE,exponentiate=TRUE,effects="ran_vals")
```

Comment: Hi @user289172, can you help add an explanation to the answer. I think it helps OP much better than just code